# How can I reboot Linux without actually rebooting?

Tags: linux, debian, linux-mint, mate

My computer has an issue where it starts freezing on and off and whatever program is active pegs the CPU. I have to reboot to fix it, restarting the program e.g. Firefox doesn't work.

Is there a way I can power cycle as much of the hardware as possible without actually rebooting? Can I unload and load all the drivers?

Comment: Maybe it would be better to fix the freezing issues rather than try to get around a known working solution to the symptom (freezing is a symptom, not the actual problem).

Comment: use [kexec](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kexec) reboot

Comment: @acejavelin I've tried this with no luck. It's not a specific process that causes the freezing so I don't know where to go next.

Answer (score 1):

You can unload many drivers and OS components by changing the run level of the system. On sysV systems the command `init x` was used to change to run level x, but systemd based systems have a different 'init' implementation.

If you have a systemd based system they have provided the `telinit x`command to provide equivalent capability.

Run levels are defined as

> 0 Halt    Shuts down system.
>
> 1 Single-User Mode    Does not configure network.   interfaces, start
>   daemons, or allow non-root logins.
>
> 2 Multiuser Mode  Does not configure network interfaces or start
>   daemons.
>
> 3 Multi-User Mode with Networking Starts the system normally.
>
> 4 Undefined   Not used/User-definable.
>
> 5 X11 As runlevel 3 + display.   manager(X).
>
> 6 Reboot  Reboots the system.

Switch to run level 1 then back to 5

```
telinit 1
telinit 5
```

Comment: This is a good answer but I'm hoping for something that doesn't kill all my processes or I may as well perform a normal restart.

Comment: Switching between runlevel 3 and 5 will a good first pass - if it fixes it look at what processes and drivers (lsmod) were unloaded. Once you have that list you can unload them one by one to find the offending program or driver.

Comment: Switching between 3 and 5 seems to have no effect.